# Missing insert into table in try catch

Tags: c#, sql-server, try-catch, missing-data

I have a C# app that reads a service bus and execute a stored procedure. It has 5 steps, one to insert this data into a table and then manipulate it (its our ETL). The DB is SQL Server.

The process is inserting data correctly into `STG.Table1`, but the second statement that inserts into `DWH.Table1` sometimes doesn't insert but neither catch the error into the Log nor the C# app. The validated column its an computed column to validate if the json is valid.

For nearly the 200k records that I have I missed 5k, I'm missing like 3% data in the `DWH.Table1` table.

Here is my code. I hope you can help me with this I really appreciated.

My stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @tableid TABLE (id bigint);
DECLARE @id BIGINT;
DECLARE @json_id VARCHAR(32);

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO STG.Table1 (c1, c2) 
    OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @tableid 
    VALUES (@v1, @v2);

COMMIT TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY

    SELECT @id = id FROM @tableid

    SELECT @json_id = JSON_VALUE(t.json,'$.json_id')
    FROM STG.Table1 t
    INNER JOIN @tableid doc ON t.id = doc.id
    WHERE validated = 'True'
    
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    
        INSERT INTO DWH.Table1 ([Id], [json_id])
            SELECT  
                t.id,
                JSON_VALUE(t.json,'$.json_id') transaction_id
            FROM 
                STG.Table1 t
            INNER JOIN 
                @tableid t1 ON t.id = t1.id
            WHERE 
                validated = 'True'
        
    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    SELECT id FROM @tableid
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE
        @errorLine INT = ERROR_LINE(),
        @errorProcedure NVARCHAR(128) = ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
        @errorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @reportMessage NVARCHAR(4000)
    
    SET @reportMessage = CONCAT('Line ', @errorLine, ' :: ', @errorMessage,' :: json_id = ',@json_id)

    INSERT INTO PRC.LOGS (errorProcedure, reportMessage)  
    VALUES (@errorProcedure, @reportMessage)
        
    DELETE FROM STG.Table1
    WHERE id = @id;
    
    THROW
END CATCH
```

Comment: Considering that `@tableid` can't have more than one row, and that it only has one column, why define it as a `table` type and rather than a `bigint`? If it just so you can use `OUTPUT INTO`? If so, it would seem to make more sense to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` if I am honest. Then there's no need for `@tableid` as you can just do `SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();`. Or is your column `id` in the table `STG.Table1` defined by a `SEQUENCE`?

Comment: I tried using it, but because the C# is enabling 8 concuttency calls I have deadlocks if I use the SCOPE_IDENTITY, that's why I use the @tableid.